# How I can sum numbers until max height?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, sum

There is height list it's total 1743 cm. I have 6 cells I want to put this numbers in cells. Max height is 300 cm. I use for loop for it it will take numbers inside height list and plus them until get closer 300 cm

```
height=[67, 67, 55, 65, 65, 65, 61, 58, 40, 40, 58, 53, 59, 63, 51, 57, 43, 65, 45, 65, 61, 58, 47, 58, 65, 74, 64, 28, 61, 46, 39]

max_height=300 #cm 

sum1=0
count=0

for i in height:
 sum1=height[count]+sum1

 count+=1
 if max_height>=sum1>=250:

    print(sum1)
    sum1=0
print(sum1)
print("\n",sum(height))
```

I expected it will get 6 sum but get 7 sum.
if you run you will see (254,289,273,261,289,292,85)

Comment: can you use numbers more than once?

Comment: Hi -Zulfiqaar,  I am open to all answers . Only I have 2 rules. I have 6 cells and one time use each number in height list

Comment: are you allowed to use numpy? My recommendation would be to sort, then use cumutalive sum, ranked approach, or through minimization. This can be achieved in ~ 5 lines.

Comment: Yes,I am. Can you help me with your solution @GlobalTraveler

Comment: So the goal is to split `height` into 6 sublists, each with a sum of no more than 300? And the number of items in each sublist is not restricted. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, @Dunes. 6 Cells lower than 300 cm but. Each number in list can use only 1 time

Answer (score 1):

It is not full solution but i hope it can help you, main idea is find most nearest value to generate summ 300

```
height = [67, 67, 55, 65, 65, 65, 61, 58, 40, 40, 58, 53, 59, 63, 51, 57, 43, 65, 45, 65, 61, 58, 47, 58, 65, 74, 64, 28, 61, 46, 39]
elems = [height.pop(0)]
groups = []
while height:
    while sum(elems) <= 300:
        next_el = 0
        for elem in height:
            if sum(elems) + elem <= 300 and elem > next_el:
                next_el = elem
        if next_el:
            elems.append(height.pop(height.index(next_el)))
        else:
            print(sum(elems))
            print(elems)
            groups.append(elems)
            elems = []
            break

print('Total: ', sum([sum(x) for x in groups]))
```

my result is:

```
273
[67, 74, 67, 65]
300
[65, 65, 65, 65, 40]
300
[65, 64, 63, 61, 47]
297
[61, 61, 59, 58, 58]
281
[58, 58, 57, 55, 53]
292
[51, 46, 45, 43, 40, 39, 28]
Total:  1743
```

Comment: what I'm exactly I'm expecting this. I will try on some new examples. I'll share my solutions and vote your code

Comment: @HakanGözübüyük edited update the condition from `<` to `<=`

Answer (score 0):

This is an algorithmic problem.
The gotcha here seems to be that if you fill up one cell at a time then your values that may not fit in the latest cell may still fit in a previous cell. So you are not taking full advantage of each cell's size, for example, your first cell contains just `254` which means you can fit a whole extra `46` cms in there (which appears later in your list).

To solve it you need to actually create a representation for the cells (a `list` and/or counter, although you can always create a `sum` of the list...), and revisit cells to check if more data fits.

Comment: Hi geekfish, I put "max_height>=sum1">=250 cm to show you how it works. When I put 290 cm there. it doesn't work. And thanks for your answer. But I'm not really good at coding. I'm amateur programmer. So I don't know how I can code for check if more data fits.

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the combinations that are 6 elements long, and then you want to get is as close to 300 as possible

```
height=[67, 67, 55, 65, 65, 65, 61, 58, 40, 40, 58, 53, 59, 63, 51, 57, 43, 65, 45, 65, 61, 58, 47, 58, 65, 74, 64, 28, 61, 46, 39]

valid_combs = []

import itertools
for comb in itertools.combinations(height, 6):
    #if sum(comb) <= 300 and sum(comb) >+ 290:
    if sum(comb) == 300:
        valid_combs.append(comb)
        print(comb)
```

this will extract valid 6 length combinations from the set, and then check if it sums to 300. the commented out condition above it is if you want to have it within a range, such as 290 to 300 etc

you can modify the condition as necessary, such as `if sum(comb) >= 250`

Comment: Thank you zulfiqar for your help and different approaches to my question. I run it.  firstly I need to say there are almost infinite combinations. Secondly; you can think each numbers are boxes and when we sum boxes height it can't be over 300 cm. and we have 6 rooms we will put these boxes to the rooms. So 6 numbers combination we don't want exactly. So I can understand why you asked me combination. But I'm amateur for coding I wasn't know itertools and combination how works

Comment: There are 3604 combinations that sum up to exactly 300, pick any of them and it will be 300cm exactly. what exactly are your parameters for the result?

Comment: we don't want to write how many number will be sum gathered (height, ***6***):

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood the problem initially. But reconsidering the input, your goal is to group the data such that the sum of an unspecified length does not exceed some threshold. Using numpy this may be a good place to start:

edit: this assumes the order of the data needs to preserved, otherwise I would use a quantile based approach. 
edit2: without order preservation

```
    import numpy as np
height = np.array(\
                  [67, 67, 55, 65, 65, 65, 61, 58, 40, 40,\
                   58, 53, 59, 63, 51, 57, 43, 65, 45, 65,\
                   61, 58, 47, 58, 65, 74, 64, 28, 61, 46, 39])
height.sort()
threshold = 300
groupings = np.where(np.diff(height.cumsum() // threshold))[0]
ends      = np.hstack((groupings, height.size))
starts    = np.roll(ends.copy(), 1) + 1
starts[0] = 0

for start, end in zip(starts, ends):
    print(f'Grouping: {height[start:end]} sum: {height[start:end].sum()}')
```

Output:

```
Grouping: [28 39 40 40 43 45] sum: 235
Grouping: [47 51 53 55] sum: 206
Grouping: [58 58 58 58 59] sum: 291
Grouping: [61 61 63] sum: 185
Grouping: [65 65 65 65] sum: 260
Grouping: [65 67 67 74] sum: 273
```

Comment: I believe there is an additional goal of minimising the number of "groupings" or "cells" that are produced. That is, there exists a solution which only has 6 groupings, as opposed to the 7 your solution created. My naive attempt found a solution of `273, 300, 300, 297, 281, 292`.

Comment: where is yours @Dunes

Comment: I originally wasnt going to post it Bear Brown's seems fairly good. The output of georgiy's makes it look good too. This was my naive solution -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650119/529630

Comment: Definitely there must be 6 groupings. I believe these solutions will help in future to many people.

Comment: since most posts use sort I assume that the binning has no order to support it. I updated the code above accordingly and it produces a grouping of six, with the most readability. It is not clear from OP whether the order in the data needs to be preserved..

Comment: Btw if it is the knapsack problem then I am also not doing any form of optimization in terms of maximizing value etc. If that is the case other solutions here are better.

Comment: Thank you @GlobalTraveler . You and other dearly friends have helped me. You are really kind guys. I hope we learnt new approaches have a nice day :)

Comment: No problem! Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to find and use combinations that fill cells with exactly 300 total height. It is not optimal.

```
    import itertools

    height=[67, 67, 55, 65, 65, 65, 61, 58, 40, 40, 58, 53, 59, 63, 51, 57, 43, 65, 45, 65, 61, 58, 47, 58, 65, 74, 64, 28, 61, 46, 39]

def fill_cell(cells, comb):
    cells.append(comb) #fill cell
    for h in comb:
        del height[height.index(h)] #delete elemets from heights array

cells = []
```

When **first** required combination is found - I `fill_cell` and delete used elements from `height` array.

 As we don't have number of items per cell restriction - I will vary this number.

In this case there is combination of 7 items with total height sum - 300:

```
for comb in itertools.combinations(height, 7):
    if sum(comb) == 300:
        print(comb) #(55, 40, 40, 53, 45, 28, 39)
        fill_cell(cells,comb)
        print(len(height)) #24
        break
```

After that I found few more combinations of 5 item and with 300 total height.

```
for comb in itertools.combinations(height, 5):
    if sum(comb) == 300:
        print(comb) #(67, 67, 65, 58, 43)
        fill_cell(cells,comb)
        print(len(height)) #19
        break

for comb in itertools.combinations(height, 5):
    if sum(comb) == 300:
        print(comb)
        fill_cell(cells,comb) #(65, 65, 61, 58, 51)
        print(len(height)) #14
        break

for comb in itertools.combinations(height, 5):
    if sum(comb) == 300:
        print(comb)
        fill_cell(cells,comb) #(59, 63, 57, 47, 74)
        print(len(height)) # 9
        break
```

At this point I have 4 cells with directly 300 total height.
I didn't find more combinations with directly 300 total height.
I decided to manually define remaining cells:

```
print(cells)
print(height)

fill_cell(cells,height[:4])
fill_cell(cells,height[:])

print("Result:")
for c in cells:
    print(sum(c), c)

print("Total height: ", sum([sum(c) for c in cells]))
```

Finally:

```
Result:
300 (55, 40, 40, 53, 45, 28, 39)
300 (67, 67, 65, 58, 43)
300 (65, 65, 61, 58, 51)
300 (59, 63, 57, 47, 74)
249 [65, 65, 61, 58]
294 [58, 65, 64, 61, 46]
Total height:  1743
```

**Update:**
Following code do the same. It iteratively changes combination parameters and reduces height limit if combination with 300 height didn't found:

```
import itertools

height=[67, 67, 55, 65, 65, 65, 61, 58, 40, 40, 58, 53, 59, 63, 51, 57, 43, 65, 45, 65, 61, 58, 47, 58, 65, 74, 64, 28, 61, 46, 39]

def fill_cell(cells, comb):
    cells.append(comb) #fill cell
    for h in comb:
        del height[height.index(h)] #delete elemets from heights array

cells = []
max_height = 300
max_elements = 7
elements = max_elements
cell_filled = True


while height:
    if cell_filled == False:
        elements-=1
    if elements==0:
        elements = max_elements
        max_height-=1

    for comb in itertools.combinations(height, min(elements,len(height))):
        if sum(comb) == max_height:
            print(comb)
            fill_cell(cells, comb)
            print(len(height))
            cell_filled = True
            break
        cell_filled = False


print("Result:")
for c in cells:
    print(sum(c), c)

print("Total height: ", sum([sum(c) for c in cells]))
```

Comment: Hi @Georgiy your solution is similar with Zulfiqaar and nice. But we don't want to write how many number will be sum  gathered  (height, ***5***):

Comment: I agree with You. I updated code

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to solve is computationally complex. It looks like a variant of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). This is a greedy approach, but it is fairly fast. Because it's greedy it is possible that it may fail to find a solution if one exists.

eg. `[120, 120, 100, 80, 65, 65]` with max height of 300 has a minimal solution of `[[120, 100, 80], [120, 65, 65]]`, but this algorithm fails to find it, and instead returns `[[120, 120], [100, 80, 65], [65]]`

```
height=[67, 67, 55, 65, 65, 65, 61, 58, 40, 40, 58, 53, 59, 63, 51, 57, 43, 65, 45, 
    65, 61, 58, 47, 58, 65, 74, 64, 28, 61, 46, 39]
max_height=300 #cm 


heights = sorted(height, reverse=True)
groups = []

while heights:
    # whilst there are still items in heights, create a new group of heights
    # with sum no more than 300.
    group = []

    # greedily fill up each group with largest possible values that can fit
    for h in heights:
        if sum(group) + h <= 300:
            group.append(h)

    # remove the values in the group from the list of candidate heights
    for g in group:
        heights.remove(g)

    groups.append(tuple(group))

# output
for g in groups:
    print(g, '->', sum(g))
```

gives:

```
(74, 67, 67, 65) -> 273
(65, 65, 65, 65, 40) -> 300
(65, 64, 63, 61, 47) -> 300
(61, 61, 59, 58, 58) -> 297
(58, 58, 57, 55, 53) -> 281
(51, 46, 45, 43, 40, 39, 28) -> 292
```

Note that the first group it found is actually the worst in terms of how close to the limit it is. This goes back to the initial point about this algorithm being greedy and not always finding the solution with the minimum number of groups.

Comment: it is completely looks like good. I will try it

Comment: Hey @Dunes I used it that code is working pretty well but if there is one list too. box_no=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31] I got a problem with matching them because there are same numbers in heights. and when I write code "box_no[heights.index(h)]" it's confusing. Do you have any idea for it ?